# How to list all computers and the last time they were logged onto in AD?

Tags: c#, directoryservices

I am trying to retrieve a list of Computer Names and the date they were last logged onto from Active Directory and return them in a datatable.
Getting the names is easy enough but when I try to add the "lastLogon" or "lastLogonTimestamp" like shown below, the only values I get for the lastLogonTimestamp is "System._ComObject"

```
public DataTable GetListOfComputers(string domainName)
{
  DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=" + domainName + ",DC=com");
  DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
  string query = "(objectclass=computer)";
  search.Filter = query;

  search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
  search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lastLogonTimestamp");

  SearchResultCollection mySearchResultColl = search.FindAll();

  DataTable results = new DataTable();
  results.Columns.Add("name");
  results.Columns.Add("lastLogonTimestamp");

  foreach (SearchResult sr in mySearchResultColl)
  {
    DataRow dr = results.NewRow();
    DirectoryEntry de = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
    dr["name"] = de.Properties["Name"].Value;
    dr["lastLogonTimestamp"] = de.Properties["lastLogonTimestamp"].Value;
    results.Rows.Add(dr);
    de.Close();
  }

  return results;
}
```

If I query AD using a tool like LDP I can see that the property exists and is populated with data.
How can I get at this info?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It'd be easier to use the ComputerPrincipal class and a PrincipalSearcher from System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(new ComputerPrincipal(pc));
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> psr = ps.FindAll();
foreach (ComputerPrincipal cp in psr)
{
    DataRow dr = results.NewRow();
    dr["name"] = cp.Name;
    dr["lastLogonTimestamp"] = cp.LastLogon;    
    results.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**The way to treat the property 'lastLogonTimestamp' retrieved from a DirectoryEntry is to convert it to IADSLargeInteger

from:
http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/31/159934.aspx**

The __ComObject returned for these types is IADsLargeInteger for the
numeric values, and IADsSecurityDescriptor for SecurityDescriptors.

You can include a reference on the COM tab to Active DS Type Lib and get
the definition for these interfaces or manually define them. Here is a
sample:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

//This is the managed definition of this interface also found in
ActiveDs.tlb
[ComImport]
[Guid("9068270B-0939-11D1-8BE1-00C04FD8D503")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
internal interface IADsLargeInteger
{
    [DispId(0x00000002)]
    int HighPart{get; set;}
    [DispId(0x00000003)]
    int LowPart{get; set;}
}

class Class1
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryEntry entry = new
DirectoryEntry("LDAP://cn=user,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com");
        if(entry.Properties.Contains("lastLogon"))
        {
            IADsLargeInteger li =
(IADsLargeInteger)entry.Properties["lastLogon"][0];    
            long date = (long)li.HighPart << 32 | (uint)li.LowPart;
            DateTime time = DateTime.FromFileTime(date);
            Console.WriteLine("Last logged on at: {0}", time);
        }
    }

}
```

David Stucki
Microsoft Developer Support

Comment: I think I need an IADSLargeInteger for setting the "accountExpires" property too.  How do I define the "LargeInteger" class - your code doesn't specify.  Do I just create a new class and inherit/implement IADsLargeInteger?

Comment: @Michael Bray Add reference to COM-Object "Active DS Type Library", ActiveDs.IADsLargeInteger ISomeAdTime = (ActiveDs.IADsLargeInteger)Iter;
                                    long lngSomeAdTime = (long)ISomeAdTime.HighPart << 32 | (uint)ISomeAdTime.LowPart;
                                    System.DateTime someAdTime = System.DateTime.FromFileTime(lngSomeAdTime);

Comment: Why use ***ActiveDs*** (COM) and not `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try using [IADsLargeInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa706037(VS.85).aspx) ([Source](http://securitythroughabsurdity.com/2005/12/active-directory-and.html))

```
DirectoryEntry user = DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + strDN);
if (user.Properties.Contains("lastlogontimestamp"))
{
  // lastlogontimestamp is a IADsLargeInteger
  IADsLargeInteger li = (IADsLargeInteger) 
  user.Properties["lastlogontimestamp"][0];
  long lastlogonts = 
      (long)li.HighPart << 32 | (uint)li.LowPart;
  user.Close();
  return DateTime.FromFileTime(lastlogonts);
}
```

Comment: IADsLargeInteger: COM-Object in "Active DS Type Library", Namespace ActiveDs

Comment: Better use `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` neither ***ActiveDS COM***. _IMHO_

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer to the original question is to access the property on your search result:

```
sr.Properties["lastLogonTimestamp"][0].ToString()
```

`DateTime.FromFileTimeUTC(long.Parse(sr.Properties["lastLogonTimestamp"][0].ToString()))` to obtain a datetime value

I'm having a similar issue, I can access the `lastLogonTimestamp` property in the `SearchResult` and obtain a value in the indexed result but after using `SearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry()` I am not able to access a valid result for the `lastLogonTimestamp` property on the **DirectoryEntry**.

Has anyone else run into this issue with the `DirectoryEntry` returned from `SearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry()` as it relates to access to the `lastLogonTimestamp` property?

Comment: I agree. Better use `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` neither ***ActiveDS COM***